# SuSE Enterprise Linux 10 reports "write error: disk full?" even though there are 13TB available

Tags: linux, lvm, sles

So, I recently added some disk to a system and everything seemed to be peachy, the extending of the LVM went fine and so did the filesystem resize. However, when a user logs on to the system and tries editing or creating a file in his/hers home directory the message "write error: disk full?" appears out of nowhere.

Checking a df -h reports this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             133G  109G   17G  87% /
udev                  3.0G  200K  3.0G   1% /dev
/dev/sda1             297M   19M  263M   7% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvhome 15T  2.4T   13T  16% /home
```

Has anyone ever encountered this before?

Sorry if the information provided is insufficient, if something is lacking just let me know so that I can provide it.

Comment: what filesystem is on /dev/mapper/vg00-lvhome?

Comment: the filesystem is ext3

Comment: Is the file system in good shape? Does `dmesg` return I/O errors or similar? Can you create new files to /home as root? More info needed! :)

Comment: Hello Janne, thanks for your input. Dmesg does not report any IO errors. Yes, it is possible to create files as the root user.

Comment: Are the quotas in use? SELinux? File/directory permissions ok?

Comment: Nope, no quotas in use and no SELinux. The file/dir permissions looks just fine .. drwxr-xr-x on the users home directories.

Comment: Just an idea, you said you extended the lvm: What's the blocksize of the ext3 filesystem? For 16TB, you need a 4kb blocksize (which should be the norm).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your /home partition has run out of inodes. You can check your inode usage with `df -i`.

Comment: No there seems to be inodes left, df -i reports that the inode usage for /home is at 1%